# Get an element from a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I have the following class file

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class gif
{
    public:
        gif(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>>& textures);
        sf::Texture getAt(int);
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>> textures;
};

gif::gif(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>>& c)
{
    textures = c;
}

sf::Texture& gif::getAt(int index)
{
    return textures.at(index);
}
```

the variable textures does not seem to work like a traditional vector would and does not have an `at(int)` function to point to an element in my vector. How would I be able to point to a certain `sf::Texture` in `textures` using an `integer`.

I have tried searching around google but do not seem to be able to find anything that would help me on this. Am I just not understanding `std::shared_ptr` correctly? If I am not then how would I use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variables.at()` is going to return an object of type `std::shared_ptr<sf::texture>`, which does not implicitly convert to `sf::texture&`. You need to dereference it with `operator*`:

```
sf::Texture& gif::getAt(int index)
{
    return *(textures.at(index));
}
```